# SQL Scanning table to update the value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have following table

```
Key ID  Value  
1    1    C  
2    1    C  
3    1    I  
4    2    C  
5    2    C  
6    2    C  
7    1    C
```

If the value of value column is I then want to update previous records of same `ID` to `I`.

For example `ID` 1 has last recod with value `I` so want to update first 2 records of `ID` 1 to `I`.
But ID 1 with Key 7 value should not change

I can do self join and update previous records using Key value is less than current key value etc..
But table has large number of records so it takes long time to scan through the table for each Id value.
Can I Use lag function but offset value will be entire table.
So not sure which is the best solution. Or is there any other option other than self join and lag.

---

Comment: is it SQL Server or postgresql?

Comment: And what if it was Key = 7 that was I and not Key = 3? Would you still want Key = 1 - 3 to be updated, even with the ID = 2 rows between those sets of ID = 1?

Comment: If Key 7 has I  value then I want all rows before that with ID 1 updated with I . Not ID 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this (or the alternate below the Results):

```sql
SET NOCOUNT ON;
DECLARE @Data TABLE
(
  [Key] INT NOT NULL,
  [ID] INT NOT NULL,
  [Value] VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO @Data VALUES (1, 1, 'C');
INSERT INTO @Data VALUES (2, 1, 'C');
INSERT INTO @Data VALUES (3, 1, 'I');
INSERT INTO @Data VALUES (4, 2, 'C');
INSERT INTO @Data VALUES (5, 2, 'C');
INSERT INTO @Data VALUES (6, 2, 'C');
INSERT INTO @Data VALUES (7, 1, 'C');

;WITH cte AS
(
  SELECT DISTINCT tmp.ID,
         MAX(tmp.[Key]) OVER(PARTITION BY tmp.[ID]) AS [MaxKeyOfI]
  FROM   @Data tmp
  WHERE  tmp.[Value] = 'I'
)
UPDATE tbl
SET    tbl.[Value] = 'I'
--SELECT tbl.*
FROM   @Data tbl
INNER JOIN cte
        ON cte.[ID] = tbl.[ID]
        AND cte.MaxKeyOfI > tbl.[Key]
WHERE  tbl.Value <> 'I';


SELECT *
FROM @Data;
```

Returns:

```
Key ID  Value
1   1   I
2   1   I
3   1   I
4   2   C
5   2   C
6   2   C
7   1   C
```

And if you change Key 3 to C and Key 7 to I, it will change Keys 1 - 3, leaving Keys 4 - 6 alone.

**OR**, you could try the following instead, which finds the `[Key]` values and uses them in the UPDATE so that the UPDATE itself is based on the PK field only:

```sql
;WITH maxkeys AS
(
  SELECT DISTINCT tmp.ID,
         MAX(tmp.[Key]) OVER(PARTITION BY tmp.[ID]) AS [MaxKeyOfI]
  FROM   @Data tmp
  WHERE  tmp.[Value] = 'I'
), others AS
(
  SELECT tmp2.[Key],
         tmp2.[ID]
  FROM   @Data tmp2
  INNER JOIN maxkeys
          ON maxkeys.[ID] = tmp2.[ID]
         AND maxkeys.MaxKeyOfI > tmp2.[Key]
  WHERE  tmp2.Value <> 'I'
)
UPDATE tbl
SET    tbl.[Value] = 'I'
--SELECT tbl.*
FROM   @Data tbl
INNER JOIN others tmp
        ON tmp.[Key] = tbl.[Key];
```

Comment: @TD2013 Yer welcome. Which version did you go with? Did you performance test both against the actual table? I am curious which is better since you need to scan all of the rows at some point (well, depending on indexes) to know which ones need to be updated, but I suspect doing the UPDATE against the Key field only (the alternate query) would be better on the UPDATE, but not sure if it is worse on the initial lookup.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT  *, 
            MAX([Key]) OVER(PARTITION BY ID) MaxKey
    FROM dbo.YourTable 
)
UPDATE A
SET Value = 'I'
FROM CTE A
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM CTE
             WHERE [Key] = A.MaxKey
             AND Value = 'I');
```

[**Here is a sqlfiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f90897/1) with a demo of it.

And the results are:

```
╔═════╦════╦═══════╗
║ Key ║ ID ║ Value ║
╠═════╬════╬═══════╣
║   1 ║  1 ║ I     ║
║   2 ║  1 ║ I     ║
║   3 ║  1 ║ I     ║
║   4 ║  2 ║ C     ║
║   5 ║  2 ║ C     ║
║   6 ║  2 ║ C     ║
╚═════╩════╩═══════╝
```

Comment: : @Llamak this should work  but if I add another row after I value then value should not change for the record that comes after only previous records.For examle add (7, 1, 'C') in the table this value should remain 'C'

Comment: :@Lamak I want key 7 to stay same but want Key 1 and 2 change to I

Comment: @TD2013 Then you should've written that in your question instead of "If the **latest value** of value column is I then want to update previous records of same ID to I"

Comment: Updated my question sorry for the confusion

Comment: @TD2013 Well, now it's a completely different question and seems like the approach you explained is the right way to do it

Comment: :@Lamak thanks for your time. Sorry for not composing my question correctly at the first time

Answer (score 0):

Here is one method.  It uses a CTE to find the ids that meet the condition of the last row being an `'I'`.  It then uses this list for the update:

```
with ids as (
      select id
      from (select ft.*, row_number() over (partition by id order by [key] desc) as seqnum
            from followingtable ft
           ) t
      where seqnum = 1 and value = 'I'
     )
update followingtable
    set value = 'I'
    where id in (select id from ids);
```

EDIT:

You can identify groups of adjacent ids by using the different of `row_numbers()` approach.  So this will identify the groups:

```
select t.*,
       (row_number() over (order by [key]) - row_number() over (partition by id order by [key]) as grp
from followingtable t;
```

You can then use this information in the above query:

```
with ft as (
      select t.*,
             (row_number() over (order by [key]) - row_number() over (partition by id order by [key])) as grp
      from followingtable t;
     ),
     idgrp as (
      select id, grp
      from (select ft.*, row_number() over (partition by id, grp order by [key] desc) as seqnum
            from followingtable ft
           ) t
      where seqnum = 1 and value = 'I'
     )
update ft
    set value = 'I'
    where exists (select 1 from idgrp where idgrp.id = ft.id and idgrp.grp = ft.grp);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Window Function` to find the latest value in a group

```
CREATE TABLE #test1([Key] INT,ID    INT,Value VARCHAR(2))

INSERT #test1
VALUES (1,1,'C' ),(2,1,'C' ),(3,1,'I' ),
       (4,2,'C' ),(5,2,'C' ),(6,2,'C' ) 

;WITH cte
     AS (SELECT Row_number() OVER(partition BY ID ORDER BY [key] DESC) rn,
                *
         FROM   #test1)
UPDATE A
SET    Value = b.value
FROM   #test1 A
       JOIN cte b
         ON a.ID = b.ID
            AND b.Value = 'I'
WHERE  rn = 1
```